# Since AngularJS 1.4 : protractor don't find ng-bind-html by.binding in a parametrized table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, ng-bind-html

Since I upgrade AngularJS to 1.4 release, my protractor tests cases are KO.
The test KO is the following :

```
var allRows = element.all(by.repeater('row in displayedElts'));
expect(allRows.count()).to.eventually.equal(1);
allRows.first().then(function (row) {
    row.element(by.binding('row.label')).then(function (elm1) {
    ...
    }
}
```

The error message is :

```
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.binding("row.label")
```

The html code is the following :

```
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat-start="row in displayedElts">
        <td ng-repeat="col in tableSpec.columns" ng-bind-html="row[col.field] | cldApply:col.filter"></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My tableSpec object is like the following :

```
$scope.tableSpec= {
    columns: [
       {
          field: 'label',
          labelKey: 'commons.label',
          filter : 'cldNone'
       },
       ...
   ]
}
```

The code of the filter cldApply (if needed) :

```
filter('cldApply', [ '$log', '$translate', '$sce',
    function ($log, $translate, $sce) {
        return function (value, filterName, bool1, bool2) {
            var ret;
            switch(filterName) {
                    case 'cldNone' :
                        ret = '' + formatNone(value, bool1);
                        break;
                    ...
                    default :
                        ret = 'unknown filter '+filterName;
                        break;
            }
            // ngSanitize to trust the html returned
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(ret);
        };
    }]);
```

The filter applies the trustAsHtml sanitize code before displaying.

This code was running normally before upgrade to AngularJS 1.4

Any clues will be greatly appreciated cause I'm stuck with this case.

Comment: Have you tried `by.exactBinding("row.label")` instead?

Comment: Thank's for your suggestion but the result is similar :  NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.exactBinding("row.label")